# SSIS Conditional Split Error Output not writing any data to table

Tags: sql, ssis

I have created this simple SSIS package:
[image: img1]
This is my conditional split:
[image: img2]
This is the Configure Error Output:
[image: img3]
I am getting this error when running:

> [ErrorTable [52]] Warning: Rows sent to the error output(s) will be
> lost. Add new data flow transformations or destinations to receive
> error rows, or reconfigure the component to stop redirecting rows to
> the error output(s).

Before I got this error it was creating the error table but did not write any rows so I changed it to redirect row and now have this error. I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: In your condition why don't you just try : CustomerAmountCurrency <=0 ?

Comment: Did you create the Error table already ? Because I can clearly see that it's not detecting the columns.

Comment: As mentioned below, the "Error" path is legitimately for errors. I suggest you rename your  `Output Name` to something other than Errors, then it will become clear that you actually have three output paths: Default, your conditinal split, and an error path

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue and think I found the answer.

The output from your conditional split should not be the red "Error" path, but another output path (blue) to the "Error" file.

I kept expecting the red path to output the data from the conditional split, but it didn't because there actually weren't any errors.

I'm learning here, but I'm guessing the red "error" path is for actual data issues and not the conditional split functions.

Hope that helps!  I